# Pass model to a view with view name in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.Net MVC 4 application, I would like to do send a model to an specific view. Here is the pseudocode-

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        A_Model model=new A_Model();
        return View(model, "ViewName");
    }
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
return View("ViewName", model);
```